# Is it possible to run JHipster Microservices locally that are managed with JHipster Registry in the cloud?

Tags: heroku, jhipster, jhipster-registry

When I run *JHipster Registry* in the cloud (ex: Heroku) and runs without problems and I can access correctly through the URL (ex: my-jhipster-registry.herokuapp.com). I could use this *JHipster Registry* to manage *JHipster Microservices* (gateways or applications) that are not in the cloud? If this is possible, how?

This doubt arises from the need to **NOT** have install *JHipster Registry* locally (on my laptop) during development and read the official guide [running in the cloud](http://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#installation).

Scenario expected during development:

- JHipster Registry in cloud (Heroku)
- JHipster Microservices in local (laptop)

I thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work as long as your services can connect to your registry and they expose IP addresses that can be reached by other services (a service running in the cloud will not be able to connect to a service running on your laptop).

You may need a real certificate on registry that match your domain name for using https.

Comment: Thank u @gaël-marziou, so i can config this in the property (application-*.yml) of ms? `eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
    client:
        service-url:
            defaultZone: *url_registry_in_cloud*`